# Tornado frame src not working

Tags: python, tornado

I am using Tornado and I have the following code:

```
class UserHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = self.get_argument("username")
        self.set_cookie("user", user)
        out = tableize(user)
        self.render('chat.html',table=out)
```

now, chatter.html looks like this:

```
<iframe src="{{ static_url('mess.html') }}" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
```

where mess.html is:

```
<div id="chat">
    {% for x in table %}
        <b> x </b>
    {% end %}
</div>
```

My question is, how do I pass the 'table' argument to mess.html?  I can't figure out how to make it display properly.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It does not make sense to pass anything to a static resource, that's why it's called static...

Comment: @mensi oh sorry the static_url part was a mistake.  My question is what do I change static_url to, and how do I pass it the table argument?

Comment: Why do you want to put this in an iframe?

Comment: haha thats just a cheap hack because I wanted to auto-refresh that part very often, and if I refresh the whole page, it's difficult to enter text into a textbox.

Comment: I wanted to refresh it often because the variable table changes a lot, and that needs to be reflected on the page.  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I think that is an entirely different question, since you would have to implement another request handler only delivering the page for your frame. Also, refreshing is perhaps not so smart for a chat application, have a look at long-polling and websockets. There should be opensource chat solutions that you can look at to get an idea. Polling via refresh will only put high load on your server.

Comment: Oh thanks, but just for the sake of knowledge, I'd like to still do it this way.  I took a look at the opensource solutions though so thanks!  Is there any way I can easily update the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `{% include %}` in the [Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/template.html), it might do what you are trying to achieve. Instead of using an iframe, directly do `{% include "mess.html" %}`.

If you want to keep the independent frame so you can refresh individually, you have to consider the iframe being a separate request. As such, you also have to provide its own `RequestHandler` where you get your cookie and then generate the table for your user. You then set the iframe src to be the URL you chose for this `RequestHandler`.

Comment: sorry I thought that was working, but how do I refresh mess.html?

Comment: adjusted answer. I hope you get the drift... basically just create a different page like your `UserHandler` with only the table.

Comment: I used
<iframe src="/frame" width="350" height="500"></iframe>
but its not working... is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Could you adjust your question to show what you have now? Including your handler for `/frame` and the url map

Comment: Here is the new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128832/tornado-iframe-src

Comment: @Abs You need to put both the handler for `/frame` rendering the table and your existing `UserHandler` rendering chat.html into your application. Have a look at the tornado examples on how to have multiple Handlers/URLs in your application.

Comment: yeah sorry that question only includes the relevant part of the code - the UserHandler rendering chat.html and its corresponding route are still there.