# Tornado iframe src

Tags: iframe, tornado

I am trying to use an iframe in the following way:

```
<iframe src="????" width="350" height="500"></iframe>
```

where the Tornado server look like this:

```
class FrameHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = self.get_argument("username")
        self.set_cookie("user", user)
        out = tableizer(user)
        self.render('messages.html',table=out)

application = tornado.web.Application(
    [
        (r"/frame", FrameHandler),
    ], 
    debug=True,
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ""),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
)
```

How do I get my iframe to display messages.html?

Comment: Please improve your question. What is criteria of "properly"?

Comment: Sorry I was wondering how I should display it at all in the first place.

Comment: Where page, on which iframe placed, served?

Answer (score 0):

The handler looks good. You only need to substitue `????` in

```
<iframe src="????" width="350" height="500"></iframe>
```

with:

```
<iframe src="/frame?user=whoever" width="350" height="500"></iframe>
```